# Is there a Stack Exchange site for running commands on a sungrid server?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I don't know if `qsub` questions belong on Stack Overflow. Is there a domain that is better suited for those types of questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know if `qsub` questions belong in stack overflow. Is there a domain that is better suited for those types of questions?

Seems that SO **has a [qsub](/questions/tagged/qsub) tag**, so I'd say it's recommended to ask it there. Also, I saw there is no specific qsub.SE or similar. The [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qsub/info) reads:

> Qsub is a job submission command for high performance computing jobs. It is used by some resource managers and some schedulers, a few of which are TORQUE, PBSPro, OpenPBS, and **SGE**. It has many different options and is the way that a job (work request) gets queued for consideration in the cluster.
>
> Questions with the "qsub" tag should clearly indicate which resource manager or scheduler is being used.

As you can see it includes SGE servers. Be sure to do as suggested and clearly indicate the manager you are using so you can get better help.